# How could I use 3 PickerViews in the same View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

How could I use 3 PickerViews in the same View vertically?
(I can't set height..)
Because I try so many times,But it's still no work.
THANKS...

Comment: why you want to do so what are you trying to do? elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need three picker view in any case if you want to show three type items then you can use cthree components in single pickerview.use this datasource method
 `- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView` for doing this.

Comment: I try to do this way.
But user wanna have 3 pickerViews in the same view...
so...I have to try what them want..